# Cannot find module 'path'

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm attempting to learn Typescript and thought I should also make my webpack config in `.ts`. This is my `webpack.config.ts`:

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import * as path from 'path';

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    entry: path.resolve('src/main.ts'),

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve( 'dist')
    }
}

export default config;
```

As well as my `package.json`:

```
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "webpack --config devtools/webpack.config.ts --display-error-details",
    "post-build": "webpack-dev-server --config devtools/webpack.config.ts --mode development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

The error I get when running npm run build is:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'
```

I have also tried requiring path, but then I get a different error saying it cant find module require.

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Did you run `npm install --save path`?

Comment: @mhatch `path` is a global module in node which is available by default

Answer (score 110):

TypeScript needs typings for *any* module, except if that module is not written in TypeScript.

```bash
 npm i @types/node -D
```

You may also need to add `"types": [ "node" ]` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Don't forget to add `"types": ["node"]` to tsconfig.json.  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799541/4808079)

Comment: @SephReed No, this is not needed. Types from `@types` folder are loaded automatically. Unless there are new rules which I am not aware of

Comment: "node" type does work automatically until you add explicit "types" definition to your tsconfig. when "types" is present, you should add "node" to the list.

Answer (score 12):

Using

```
"types": ["node"]
```

in `tsconfig.json` as mentioned in the comments, solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I'm using a TypeScript monorepo and none of the solutions here worked for me. Adding `"typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"]` to the `compilerOptions` of the `tsconfig.json` file within a specific project worked for me. The IDE now also recognizes the type of `__dirname`

Comment: Thanks! This helped me. I had converted a project from using separate modules to a nested monorepo with a workspace definition. After seeing your answer, I realized that all the tsconfig files referered to "./node_modules/@types" instead of the new path in the workspace directory, "../node_modules/@types".

Answer (score 0):

I had to do all this

1. [VS Code][Terminal] upgrade typescript: `npm i typescript/@latest -g`
2. [VS Code][Terminal] install node types: `npm i @types/node --save-dev`
3. [VS Code][tsconfig.json] add types: `"compilerOptions": {types:["node"]}`
4. [VS Code][Explorer] delete package-lock.json and node_modules
5. [VS Code][Terminal] install: `npm install`
6. [VS Code] Restart VS Code
7. [VS Code][Terminal] test: `tsc`

Answer (score -5):

First of all no need of  `.ts`  extension for webpack config file. Its just internal purpose for building the bundle. Use normal  `.js`  file.

Webpack is not ran by browser, its by `Node Js`  which runs webpack module and make bundle as per config.

Now `Node Js` understand its own module system is which is `require`

So it would be like below: **require** in below is Node Js module importing syntax.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
```

Comment: Writing your webpack config in typescript means your config is type checked and helps you avoid errors.  The OP specifically asked for how to make this work in typescript

Answer (score -6):

Try using `require` syntax rather than `import` & change `webpack.config.ts` to the following code

## webpack.config.ts

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    entry: path.resolve('src/main.ts'),

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve( 'dist')
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

And then run `npm run build`