# Typescript, "process" does not exist

Tags: node.js

I installed `npm i @types/node` but process still doesn't register as existing.  What else do I need to do to have type definitions for node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You not only have to install the types for node (ie `npm i @types/node`), but you also have to list "node" under "types" in tsconfig.json

```
// example tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES2018",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's extremely important to note that if you update "types" or "typesRoots", you are creating an exclusive list to include (which you'll have to maintain), whereas leaving it at default makes *all* relevant available type locations available.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35728982)